# Expand/collapse a menu list animated and only with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to make:

[image: Visual aid]

1. Click on "PORTFOLIO";
2. Pushes everything down smoothly;
3. New links fade-in smoothly;
4. Click on "PORTFOLIO" again, do everything in reverse;

My current code;

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle]').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).data("toggle"),
            $object = $(id),
            className = "open";

        if ($object) {
            if ($object.hasClass(className)) {
                $object.removeClass(className)
            } else {
                $object.addClass(className)
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#list {
    display: none;
}
#list.open {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">A Empresa</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="hide" data-toggle="#list">Portfolio</a>
            <ul id="list">
                <li><a href="#">Comerciais</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Residenciais</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Institucionais</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Edifícios</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It's possible to accomplish this without JS, only with CSS? I have no clue whatsoever how to do the animation part, I tried CSS Transitions propriety, but didn't work.

Also, any tips for the markup and JS? I don't thinks I'm doing it the "right way"... any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: CSS does take the focus on element such as link or input, so yes , you may toggle(show/hide) a sub menu via :focus and pointer-events via CSS only :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**With only CSS** you may use `:focus` and eventually `pointer-events` if you want a toggle effect :

```css
#list {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}

a:focus+#list {
  max-height: 15em;
}
/* only select that link , here using the href attribute */
a[href="nowhere"]:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">A Empresa</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere">Portfolio</a>
      <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#">Comerciais</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Residenciais</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Institucionais</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Edifícios</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contato</a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You can even do this very little CSS without class nor id :

```css
ul a +ul {
  max-height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:0.5s linear;
  }
ul a:focus + ul {
  max-height:15em;
  }
/* only select that link , here using the href attribute */
a[href="nowhere"]:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#nowhere">Home</a>
            <ul>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere">A Empresa</a>
            <ul>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" >Portfolio</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Comerciais</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Residenciais</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Institucionais</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Edifícios</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a>
            <ul>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the menu only using css please check the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dwgpqncw/2/ also the code for the same is posted below

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>css menu</title>
<style>
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
ul{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
ul li ul{height:0px; transition:500ms all;-webkit-transition:500ms all;-moz-transition:500ms all;-o-transition:500ms all;overflow:hidden;}
ul li ul li{ transition:1300ms all;-webkit-transition:1300ms all;-moz-transition:1300ms all;-o-transition:1300ms all;opacity:0}
a{color:#000; text-transform:uppercase;}
ul li ul li a{color:red;}
/*set the height to 0 and on focus set the height to pixels calculation based on the line height*/
ul li .expandable +ul:nth-child(1),ul li .expandable +ul:nth-child(1),ul li .expandable +ul:nth-child(1),ul li .expandable +ul:nth-child(1){height:0px;overflow:hidden;}
ul li ul li{line-height:30px;font-size:16px;}
ul li .expandable{font-size:20px; line-height:35px; text-decoration:none; padding-left:20px; }
ul li .expandable:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
ul li ul li:before{padding-left:20px; content:"-"; font-size:16px; margin-left:20px}
ul li .expandable:focus{color:red;}
ul li .expandable:focus +ul:nth-child(1){height:90px;}
ul li .expandable:focus +ul:nth-child(2){height:120px;}
ul li .expandable:focus +ul:nth-child(3){height:60px;}
ul li .expandable:focus +ul:nth-child(4){height:120px;}
ul li .expandable:focus +ul:nth-child(1) li,ul li .expandable:focus +ul:nth-child(2) li,ul li .expandable:focus +ul:nth-child(3) li,ul li .expandable:focus +ul:nth-child(4) li{opacity:1;}    
</style>
</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="expandable">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home link 3 </a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>


    <li>
        <a href="#" class="expandable">A Empressa</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Empressa link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Empressa link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Empressa link 3 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Empressa link 4 </a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="expandable">Protfolio</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Protfolio link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Protfolio link 2</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>


    <li>
        <a href="#" class="expandable">Contato</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contato link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato link 3 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato link 4 </a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>


</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use the TidyUp button and follow its advice. Also, your menu doesn't have a fade effect as was requested.

Comment: I have added the fade effect now https://jsfiddle.net/dwgpqncw/1/. whats the tidyUp button?

Comment: It's right in the main menu. Move your CSS to the CSS panel and click it.